# What are the techniques used to test CSS code?

Tags: css, testing, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

We have a few internal applications that will be reusing the same CSS codebase.

Basically, these CSS files are SCSS files and we are heavily leveraging Twitter Bootstrap to cut down on development. But with more internal apps using those stylesheets, I am wondering what are the practices we can implement to ensure we will not be breaking dependent apps with our internal releases.

So my question is:

What are the different ways to test CSS code via automation if there is any?

Comment: What I mean is what automation tools do they use? I would guess they have Selenium running automation tests but what would be the logic to test the correct rendering of the applied classes? What set up do they have?

Comment: What you are trying to do is better accomplished by a human tester... automation CAN do this but, it won't have the same level of 'taste' that you as a person will or your designers' flair.

Comment: I'd be very cautious about trying to automate CSS testing. With the vagaries across different rendering engines of IE, I'd have little confidence in my styles until I looked at them with my own eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in a similar boat; a small team managing a CSS component library used across all of the companies applications. It is crucial that we produce quality code and have several techniques to ensure this happens.

This starts with testing code validation using the W3C CSS validator , we then move on to testing coding standards using CSSLint.

Once we have branched for a release we perform visual regression testing using [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) which is great but is limited to only being able to regression test in a headless WebKit browser. I believe that Selenium would be a better option as it can interface directly with the actual browser, meaning that it can be used to test in real WebKit browsers, IE and anything else you care to support. I have found Selenium tests difficult to set up (I am not a programmer) and am hoping the [Automated CSS Testing talk](http://environmentsforhumans.com/2013/css-summit/) at the CSS Summit will help to fill the gaps.

Comment: That's a great start, thank you, it pointed me to some directions and that's what I needed. Thanks! If we decide to do CSS testing seriously, I will post our practices here.